# How to install OpenAM Web Policy Agent on Windows Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: apache, httpserver, openam, forgerock

I am trying to install OpenAM using Default Configuration on Windows from the official documentation of OpenAM: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/getting-started/#create-web-policy-agent-profile

In the last step of **Setting up the Software**: [To Install OpenAM Web Policy Agent](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/getting-started/#install-web-policy-agent), they have installed OpenAM Web Policy Agent on Linux. Can someone specify the steps to install it on a Windows system.

PS - I have installed Apache HTTP Server and performed all the previous steps as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install the Web Agent on IIS or are you trying to install it via Apache HTTP Server on Windows? I assume the latter. So not much is really different between the 2 operating systems with Apache as you are just installing and enabling the agent module. All the agentadmin really does is write to the apache configuration the location of the module, the configuration location along with some syntax to turn it on. It also does some connectivity / sanity checks etc.

One thing to note is that you have referenced the OpenAM/QuickStart documentation rather than [the actual agent documentation](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam-web-policy-agents/4.1/web-pa-guide/#install-apache-web-agent) itself, where you will find far more useful information.

I am assuming that because you are using 13.5 then you are using the community edition, of which only WPA 4.x will work.

My DockerFile installs the agent like this for apache24 through the following command (using choco to install apache24). However, it can be translated quite easily and is available in the documentation:

```
RUN ["powershell", "-Command", "C:/web_agents/apache24_agent/bin/agentadmin.exe --s 'C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf' 'http://openam.xxx.xx:8080/am' 'http://agent.xxx.xx:80' '/' 'wpa-agent' 'c:/pwd.txt' --acceptLicence --forceInstall"]
```